# Cocos2D Chipmunk

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm using chipmunk and I want to stack boxes in a column, but when they collide, they bounce. I already set elasticity to 0 to all boxes, but they are still bouncing upwards.

Any suggestions to stop this behavior?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Chipmunk much. Bu it should be close to Box2D i guess.

In Box2D you can prevent it simply setting the "restitution" value to "0" for all boxes.

For example:

```
boxFixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
```

I hope this gives some idea for solving this problem in Chipmunk.

Comment: I think the equivalent to restitution for chipmunk would be elasticity, but even if I set it to 0.0f, it stills bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large the stack of boxes is, you'll need to increase the number of iterations to increase the solver's accuracy.

Comment: Oh. This is a pretty old thread, but you set the iterations on the Chipmunk space. cpSpaceSetIterations() or similar depending on if you are using a wrapper or not.